Ubuntu Apache2 Default Page as regular user only on laptop and not desktop
I'm trying to get onto the website eko4u.com which is a b2b portal where we order windows from our manufacturer. On my desktop at home I have no issues with the website and it works just fine, but when I try to get in through my laptop at our showroom I get this page:
Apache 2 Defualt Page
What can i do? It happens consistently, and 30 min later I can use it on my desktop no problem

Without knowing how your network or systems are configured, I would start by checking the /etc/hosts file on the computer with the issue and, if that does not have a specific entry for the domain, check the DNS provider for the showroom’s network.
